# File creation and download, Drive scopes, and publishing editor add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I'm working on an Forms add-on which would allow you to export survey response data and/or save it to user's Drive. Is there no way to do this other than allowing full Drive access through the most extensive scope?

And about publishing editor add-on, how does one go about with it? I'm unable to get it to G-Suite marketplace, and the original unlisted version was on Chrome Webstore. (which is now unavailable)

I tried to test it with "Integrate With Google" via the G-Suite Marketplace API, but nothing shows up when testing. I don't know why, since the add-on works as expected via "Test as extension" from Google Apps Script editor. And the "waiting for review" has been taking ages. Is there any way to know the status of it?

**EDIT:** It seems like only Drive API can be used with custom scope (after enabling it), but DriveApp always requires full-access scope. And the functions that fetch files from Drive ONLY give out those that the script has access to (created or opened with) if you're using  `drive.file` scope.
...the publishing part is still a mess though.

Comment: You should be able to upload a file with the DRIVE_FILE scope, as long as it's opened or created with the app.

Comment: @Jescanellas what does this "created with the app" work in practice? Every time I try to create new file from script, it requires the full-access Drive scope :I

Comment: It means it should be enough to upload the file, as it's being opened by the same script/app, which is your case. I just tested the drive.file scope and it worked fine. Can you post a sample of your code?

Comment: @Jescanellas Here's the code section in question (that creates the file). It just complains "Required scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",       


  
    `var myblob = Utilities.newBlob(to_file_data, 'text/csv', custfilnam)`
    `var file = DriveApp.createFile(myblob);`
    `var fileID = file.getId();`
    `var fileName = file.getName();`
    `var downurl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+fileID`

Comment: And that URL is then given out to user with `var downui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput();` `FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(downlui,"title");`

Comment: I see. [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) only works with the full Drive scope. Maybe you should try using the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) as it allows you to choose a scope between drive, drive.file or drive.appdata.

Comment: @Jescanellas Okay. I used `auth/drive.file` scope which allows me to create files via Drive API (once enabled). If you don't mind, I'd like to ask regarding this another question: how can you "check" which files you have access from script/add-on (meaning which files were created with it)? Or is it just that functions such as `Drive.Files.list();` only return those specific files? Was unable to find clear answer from documentation.

Comment: You could create an [AppDataFolder](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/appdata) to store the files there, and list them with Files.list() but using the parameter 'q' with an [appDataFolder](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files) query. Another option would be catching the FileID every time you do an upload with the script and store it somewhere, so you can access the app files when you need to.

Comment: @Jescanellas Right. I used the Drive API for my needs and it seems to work. Documentation is a pain to go through, with not enough clear examples. Like the thing that `Drive.Files.list()` returns only those that script has access to, without need to check access separately (if you use `drive.file' scope). Onto next problem: publishing add-on :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding scopes and using Drive through Apps Script, there is two things that are needed to know.

1) DriveApp class that is readily provided in Apps Script, always requires full read-write access to user's Drive. This apparently can't be changed.

2) Drive API (v2) under "Advanced Google Services" allows usage of all available Drive scopes. This, however, needs to be enabled separately.

Another thing: `drive.file` scope allows you to only access files and folders in user's Drive that have been opened or created with specific script. This includes queries, so you only get what you can access. No need to check permissions separately.